# Extracting First Name and Last Name

Tags: mysql, extract

Name field have full name in this format   `lastname,First Name`
I want to change them to be  `firstname(space)lastname`
Please help.

am trying to get SQL Syntax to accomplish this task.
for example names appear in name column like this ''Lincoln,Abraham" or"Lincoln,Abraham."
I want to create another column which will have the name like this   "Abraham Lincoln"

Comment: can you please us more detail about your issue so we can help you in good way..:)

Comment: A clean database definition would separate first name and last name into different fields.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a better design to have `first_name` and `last_name` as two separate fields in the table.
You can add those new columns like below:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD COLUMN first_name VARCHAR(255)
  , ADD COLUMN last_name VARCHAR(255)
```

After adding these columns you can copy values into them by extracting from existing `full_name_column`.

```
update table_name
   set   first_name = trim( substring_index( full_name_column, ',', -1 ) )
       , last_name  = trim( substring_index( full_name_column, ',',  1 ) )
```

**Example**: Using `substring_index`:

```
mysql> select @n:=' Lincoln,  Abraham ' name
    ->        , trim( substring_index( @n, ',', 1 ) ) last_name
    ->        , trim( substring_index( @n, ',', -1 ) ) first_name;
+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| name                | last_name | first_name |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+
|  Lincoln,  Abraham  | Lincoln   | Abraham    |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Even Ravinder has provided you better solution and with proper explanation but if still due to some reason you want to get what ever you required then you can use below query:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN `New_Name` VARCHAR(150);

UPDATE MyTable 
SET `New_Name`= CONCAT(TRIM( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Name`, ',', -1 ) ),' ',TRIM( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `Name`, ',', 1 ) ));
```

Comment: Thanks.. But i get this error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.  and Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user3518233 I think you're using MS SQL Server and not MySQL. This is a typical MS SQL Server error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help folks. Truly appreciate it.